# Set construction

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Have the set $H = \{1, 2, 3, ..., 24\}$, then construct the set:

$$ P(H) \setminus \emptyset = \{\{1\}, \{2\},..., \{24\}, \{1,2\}, ..., \{23,24\}, ..., \{1,2,3,...,24\}\}$$

The set of subsets of $P(H)$ that have cardinality 1 is given by:

$$P(H_1) = \{\{1\}, ..., \{24\}\} $$

Now, have the complement of $P(H_1)$:

$$C = P(H_1)^c = \{\{1,2\}, \{2,3\} ..., \{1,2,3,...,24\}\} $$

Suppose $h$ is a function from **N** to **R**, such that: $$h(n) = \frac{n}{60}$$

where $n$ is an arbitrary natural number.

I want to construct a subset of $C$, in which each subset of this set is the smallest subset that satisfies:

$$|s| \geq h(n)$$

For example: For h(30) = 0.5, the set of smallest subsets that satisfies the condition above is:

$$ S = \{\{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, ..., \{23,24\}\} $$

Where each $s \in S$ is the smallest subset of $C$ that satisfies $|s| \geq h(n)$.

My attempt at constructing this set is:

$$ S = \{s | inf\{|h(n) - |s||\}, s \in C, h(n) \in R \} $$

Is it correct?

Comment: What is $n$? Or should we just think of $h(n)$ as an arbitrary constant?

Comment: @Karl, i edited the question. In fact, n is an arbitraty natural number.

Comment: You are talking about power sets... where is the empty set in all of this?  If you don't want the empty set to appear, say so.

Comment: @JMoravitz You're right. Fixed!

Comment: "*fixed*"  You *should* have written this as $2^H\setminus \{\emptyset\}$.  Saying $\emptyset\not\subset 2^H$ is wrong since the emptyset is a subset of everything.  You meant to say $\emptyset\not\in\dots$ instead but in that case it is again wrong since $\emptyset$ *is* in $2^H$ where $2^H$ is defined as normally, the power set of $H$.

Comment: As an aside... the notation you use for $2^{H_k}$ is nonstandard.  Rather... we have a notation for the set of subsets of a particular size.  For a set $H$ and a size $k$ the set of subsets of $H$ of size $k$ is conveniently notated as $\binom{H}{k}$, which gives the satisfying identity that $|\binom{H}{k}|=\binom{|H|}{k}$ for sets $H$ and non-negative integer $k$.

Comment: @JMoravitz now it should be ok, i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your expression:

- Taking the absolute value of $h(n)-|s|$ is going to prevent you from distinguishing between $h(n)>|s|$ and $h(n)<|s|$.
- $\inf\{\dots\}$ is just a number, but the stuff after the $\{s|$ should be complete propositions representing *conditions* that $s$ must satisfy.
- The condition $h(n)\in\Bbb R$ has nothing to do with $s$, so it doesn't make sense here. (We aren't building a set by collecting several values of $h(n)$, we're just using $h(n)$ as a fixed constant.)

I'd approach this in two steps:

1. Figure out an expression for the size $|s|$ you're looking for. This is the smallest integer that's at least 2 and at least $h(n)$. I'd write this as $\max(2,\lceil h(n)\rceil)$.
2. Write an expression that selects the subsets of $H$ having that size. I'd write it as $\{s\subseteq H\text{ }|\text{ }|s|=\max(2,\lceil h(n)\rceil)\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your very instructive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your notation $2^{H_1}$ is somewhat unfortunate as $2^X$ is standard notation for the power set of $X$ or (essentially equivalently) the set of functions from $X$ to a set with two elements. So the notation suggests there is a set $H_1$ whose power set comprises the singletons in the power set of $H$, which is not true. I will just write $C$ for what you call $C(2^{H_1})$, the set of subsets of $H$ with at least two elements. Here is a set comprehension that gives the set $S_n$ of elements $X$ of $C$ that are minimal subject to the constraint that $|X| \ge h(n)$.

$$S_n  = \{X \in C \mid \forall Y \subseteq X\cdot |Y| \ge h(n) \Leftrightarrow Y = X\}$$

Comment: The confusion regarding the notation is indeed present, and i'll edit the question very soon. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer.